# Passing arguments to a filter - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to access route parameters within a filter?

e.g. I want to access the $agencyId parameter:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'agency'), function()
{

    # Agency Dashboard
    Route::get('{agencyId}', array('as' => 'agency', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Agency\DashboardController@getIndex'));

});
```

I want to access this $agencyId parameter within my filter:

```
Route::filter('agency-auth', function()
{
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if ( ! Sentry::check())
    {
        // Store the current uri in the session
        Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());

        // Redirect to the login page
        return Redirect::route('signin');
    }

    // this clearly does not work..?  how do i do this?
    $agencyId = Input::get('agencyId');

    $agency = Sentry::getGroupProvider()->findById($agencyId);

    // Check if the user has access to the admin page
    if ( ! Sentry::getUser()->inGroup($agency))
    {
        // Show the insufficient permissions page
        return App::abort(403);
    }
});
```

Just for reference i call this filter in my controller as such:

```
class AgencyController extends AuthorizedController {

    /**
     * Initializer.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Apply the admin auth filter
        $this->beforeFilter('agency-auth');
    }
...
```

Comment: you can use this `$agencyId=Request::segment(2)` to get the `agencyId` in filter

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Input::get` can only retrieve `GET` or `POST` (and so on) arguments.

To get route parameters, you have to grab `Route` object in your filter, like this :

```
Route::filter('agency-auth', function($route) { ... });
```

And get parameters (in your filter) :

```
$route->getParameter('agencyId');
```

---

(just for fun)
In your route

```
Route::get('{agencyId}', array('as' => 'agency', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Agency\DashboardController@getIndex'));
```

you can use in the parameters array `'before' => 'YOUR_FILTER'` instead of detailing it in your constructor.

Answer (score 14):

The method name has changed in Laravel 4.1 to `parameter`. For example, in a RESTful controller:

```
$this->beforeFilter(function($route, $request) {
    $userId = $route->parameter('users');
});
```

Another option is to retrieve the parameter through the `Route` facade, which is handy when you are outside of a route:

```
$id = Route::input('id');
```